# How to get a dictionary of lists in a .yaml file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, keras, yaml

I am running a a convolutional neural network and I would like to save the dictionary from the keras 'History' callback as an accessible file for later analysis.

To this end, I have tried to use yaml and json. However, as I realize now, json only saves strings (a complication which would presumably include some preprocessing when loading the files) and thus I would prefer to avoid it altogether.

```py
History = model.fit(X, y, epochs=1)

with open('info.yaml', 'w') as outfile:
    yaml.dump(History.history, outfile)
```

The History.history object is a dictionary:

````sh
{'loss': [0.7038881447697759], 'acc': [0.5318729], 'val_loss': [0.6777660911643625], 'val_acc': [0.6560095]}```
````

This is the output I get:

```sh
acc:
- !!python/object/apply:numpy.core.multiarray.scalar
  - &id001 !!python/object/apply:numpy.dtype
    args: [f4, 0, 1]
    state: !!python/tuple [3, <, null, null, null, -1, -1, 0]
  - !!binary |
    0ygIPw==
loss:
- !!python/object/apply:numpy.core.multiarray.scalar
  - &id002 !!python/object/apply:numpy.dtype
    args: [f8, 0, 1]
    state: !!python/tuple [3, <, null, null, null, -1, -1, 0]
  - !!binary |
    cYE6bkCG5j8=
val_acc:
- !!python/object/apply:numpy.core.multiarray.scalar
  - *id001
  - !!binary |
    PfAnPw==
val_loss:
- !!python/object/apply:numpy.core.multiarray.scalar
  - *id002
  - !!binary |
    KXB8g0Kw5T8=
```

Is there any way to preserve the dictionary structure in the output file?

Comment: The dictionary *is* preserved. It even preserves the fact that the values are not plain Python lists, but NumPy arrays.

Comment: Maybe if you convert the NumPy arrays to lists before writing the YAML file, it will look as you had expected.